# Flash messages does not match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code:

```
    <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
        <div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
            <%= message + " " + type %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

to display flash messages, and in the application_helper I have this:

```
module ApplicationHelper    

def flash_class(type)
        case type
        when :alert 
            "alert-danger"
        when :notice 
            "alert-success"
        else
            "alert-info"
        end
    end    
end
```

If I intentionally do this `<div class="alert <%= flash_class :alert %>">` it displays with the proper colour (result of the correct class in the html). Otherwise I always get this result:

[image]

I'm new at ruby-on-rails so I must have missed something simple, but I don't know what. Any help?
I'm using ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flash type has changed in (I think) Rails 4, it's a string, you're comparing symbols, so it'll never match.

Try this, it'll handle both:

```
def flash_class(type)
    case type
    when :alert, 'alert'
        "alert-danger"
    when :notice, 'notice'
        "alert-success"
    else
        "alert-info"
    end
end
```

Comment: yes I believe there has been a push to use strings over symbols since symbols are not garbage collected

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :) You were right, now the flash type is a string.

Comment: Now that I realize the problem I found the official answer here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: why not just use `case type.to_s` or `case type.to_sym`?